# Bathtub drain schedule: to keep or to replace?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, bathtub, remodeling

We're remodeling our first bathroom and learning a lot. I'm planning on having the existing cast iron tub refinished after tiling everything. But before I tile, I need to figure out what to do with the tub drain schedule.

I don't know if I should keep it or replace with PVC. It looks like it's brass and might last for a long time, but then again maybe it won't? In the pictures, you can see the overflow part looks a bit icky (corroded?).
What's the best practice here? To keep it or switch it out? When I tile everything I won't have access anymore. The schedule isn't PVC but the rest of the drain is.

Beautiful photos of gross drain:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please note that it's easier on everyone if you allow the site to self-host your images for you. This way others don't have to click the links. Simply drag your pics into the edit box where you want them (or click the "sun and mountain" icon) - the site will upload & host them for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've worked with those fittings and they are top of the line. I wouldn't be replacing them based on what I see in the pictures. You might want to remove the rubber gaskets and replace them. You'll need to stop by a plumbing supply store to get them as I doubt your home store will have them. I'm not sure what's on the other side of the wall of the drain but it's always smart to leave some sort of removable panel (you can tile it) so you can get to the faucet and drain in the event something goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you, that helps! I was planning to install an access panel on the other side to get to the valve and the drain.

Comment: I fully agree that old brass lasts forever and putting in a new rubber or silicone seal will probably be a wise choice after having things loose. Make sure to get a quality job on the refinish. I have had claw foots done with the UV epoxy that were outstanding, and have purchased them that bad jobs were done and they looked like crap. Just FYI make sure they have a solid warranty and it could last a lifetime.